# Add items into Tuples within a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks as such:

```
final_list = (1, "Baseline")
final_list2 = (1, "Baseline")
final = [final_list, final_list2]*7

values = [1.0, None, False, True, 1, 100, 'ovr', 1, 'l2', None, 'liblinear', 0.0001, 0, False]
```

I would like to insert each element from values into the corresponding element tuple in `final`. The final result would look like this:

```
[(1, 'Baseline', 1.0), (1, 'Baseline', None), (1, 'Baseline', False), (1, 'Baseline', True), (1, 'Baseline', 1), (1, 'Baseline', 100), (1, 'Baseline', 'ovr'), (1, 'Baseline', 1), (1, 'Baseline', l2), (1, 'Baseline', None), (1, 'Baseline', 'liblinear'), (1, 'Baseline', 0.0001), (1, 'Baseline',0), (1, 'Baseline', False)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You cannot insert a value into an existing tuple; you need to create new tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a list-comprehension which iterates through `values` appending `final_list` at the beginning:

```
final_list = (1, "Baseline")  
values = [1.0, None, False, True, 1, 100, 'ovr', 1, 'l2', None, 'liblinear', 0.0001, 0, False]

print([final_list + (x, ) for x in values])

# [(1, 'Baseline', 1.0),
#  (1, 'Baseline', None), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', False),
#  (1, 'Baseline', True),
#  (1, 'Baseline', 1), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 100), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 'ovr'), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 1), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 'l2'), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', None), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 'liblinear'), 
#  (1, 'Baseline', 0.0001),
#  (1, 'Baseline', 0),
#  (1, 'Baseline', False)]
```

Comment: Or, if there is indeed a difference between `final_list` and `final_list2`, then `[fl+(v,) for fl, v in zip(final, values)]` or `[fl+(v,) for fl, v in zip(itertools.cycle([final_list, final_list2]), values)]`

Comment: There is no difference. I wanted to create a nested list and figured tuples would be the way to go.